# How to save NSAttributedString to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to save the attributedString of my UItextview'text.
I tried to convert to string and save. But when I back to set the text'attributedString,it not work.

This is how I convert to String:

```
var a = String(stringInterpolationSegment: text.attributedText)
    Data.setValue(a, forKey: "font")
    Data.managedObjectContext?.save(nil)
```

This is how I back to set:

```
text.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: size)
```

but my TextView just show the AttributedSting

```
{
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fa9fa82aec0> font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt";
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n    140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n    308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 0, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
}
```

I'm sorry that I can't post images. I use the swift to do this.

**My questions: How can i do this ? Or there have another way to save the attributedText?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing NSAttributedString Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266226/storing-nsattributedstring-core-data)

Comment: @i_am_jorf this question I have been read before,it write by object-c.I don't konw how to do this yet

Comment: Please refer to the answer by pob21 in the link by i_am_jorf. It is not the accepted answer but it is the right way to do it. I do the same in my app (using Swift).

Comment: @JoeSmith thanks for your advice! I am sorry to ask a similar question.I just a swift begainner.Can you share your code if you don't mind,thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The attribute should look like this in the data model.

[image]

The header file should be modified to match this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSAttributedString * attributedText;
```

That's it. You should be able to persist your attributed string just like any other attributes.

Suppose your entity is Event, and you have an object event of type Event, you can access it as event.attributedText. Here are some sample Swift code:

```
event.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World")
let attributedString = event.attributedText
```

Let us know should you prefer the answer in your native language.

Comment: thanks for your advice! I am confused about  how to do the header file you said.I am swift begainner.Hope can be generous with your help.:-)

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 10 with automatic code generation this is a lot simpler than the other suggestions.

1. Open the data model and select the name of the Attribute
2. Open the Data Model inspector (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>)
3. Set `Attribute Type` to `Transformable`
4. Set `Custom Class` to `NSAttributedString`

[image: Screenshot of Xcode attribute inspector]

And that's it, now you can just save your data in your Swift code as you'd expect, with no need for modifying generated classes or forced casting, e.g.:

`detailItem.content = textView.attributedText`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add attributedText with a  simple workaround.

Add a attribute of type `Transformable`. After creating the .h file change the type of that attribute to `NSAttributedString`. In that attribute you can easily save the attributed string.

Hope this helps.. :)